# NG-Repeat to produce a list with dynamic classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

I'm trying to print as an li any item that matches the index of the first loop.

For example: first loop makes li's classed as cat1_li, 2nd one as cat2_li, 3rd one as cat3_li

However the closest I can get prints them all out in separate lists.
Having real trouble getting my head around using ng-repeats inside other ng-repeats and can't seem to find where the issue is. I can see why it is printing multiple lists, but not how to remedy this behaviour.

Would anyone be willing to take a look?

HTML:

```
    <div>
     <ul class="tasks" ng-repeat="cat in taskCategories.categories">
    {{ cat }}
    <li ng-repeat="tasks in tasklist.tasks | orderBy:'category' | filter: {category: cat}" class="cat{{ index + 1 }}_li">
        <span>
          <span class="panel_title">
          {{ tasks.title }}
          </span>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div
```

Object:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


$scope.taskCategories = {
    categories: [
        'work',
        'chores',
        'learning',
        'lifting'
    ]
};

$scope.tasklist = {
    tasks: [{
            title: 'Email Gregory',
            category: 'work'
        }, {
            title: 'Clean the Kitchen',
            category: 'chores'
        }, {
            title: 'AngularJS',
            category: 'learning'
        }, {
            title: 'Hose Car',
            category: 'chores'
        }, {
            title: 'Email Jethro',
            category: 'work'
        }, {
            title: '400 lbs',
            category: 'lifting'
        }
    ]
};
}]);
```

Comment: what is the rendered html and what is expected?

Comment: Are tasks supposed to be children of cat? What does your object structure look like?

Comment: The rendered HTML can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/b6sapx50/

And how I would like it to render can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/3f2anqva/

Basically, I want everything with the "work" category (or what ever the first category is) to end up with a class of "cat1_li" etc, and for them all to be in the same unordered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$parent.$index` if you're trying to use the Category's index inside the nested `ng-repeat`:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.taskCategories = {
      categories: [
        'work',
        'chores',
        'learning',
        'lifting'
      ]
    };

    $scope.tasklist = {
      tasks: [{
        title: 'Email Gregory',
        category: 'work'
      }, {
        title: 'Clean the Kitchen',
        category: 'chores'
      }, {
        title: 'AngularJS',
        category: 'learning'
      }, {
        title: 'Hose Car',
        category: 'chores'
      }, {
        title: 'Email Jethro',
        category: 'work'
      }, {
        title: '400 lbs',
        category: 'lifting'
      }]
    };
  }
]);
```

```css
.cat1_li {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cat2_li {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cat3_li {
  background-color: pink;
}

.cat4_li {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
  <ul class="tasks" ng-repeat="cat in taskCategories.categories">
    {{ cat }}
    <li ng-repeat="tasks in tasklist.tasks | orderBy:'category' | filter: {category: cat}" class="cat{{ $parent.$index + 1 }}_li">
      <span>
        <span class="panel_title">
          {{ tasks.title }}
        </span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

After reading your comment in the question, you don't need two `ng-repeat` at all:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.taskCategories = {
      categories: [
        'work',
        'chores',
        'learning',
        'lifting'
      ]
    };

    $scope.tasklist = {
      tasks: [{
        title: 'Email Gregory',
        category: 'work'
      }, {
        title: 'Clean the Kitchen',
        category: 'chores'
      }, {
        title: 'AngularJS',
        category: 'learning'
      }, {
        title: 'Hose Car',
        category: 'chores'
      }, {
        title: 'Email Jethro',
        category: 'work'
      }, {
        title: '400 lbs',
        category: 'lifting'
      }]
    };
    
    $scope.mappedTasks = $scope.tasklist.tasks.map(function(task) {
      task.category = $scope.taskCategories.categories.indexOf(task.category);
      return task;
    }).sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.category > b.category;
    });;
    
    console.log($scope.mappedTasks);
  }
]);
```

```css
.cat1_li {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cat2_li {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cat3_li {
  background-color: pink;
}

.cat4_li {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
  <ul class="tasks">
    <li ng-repeat="task in mappedTasks" class="cat{{ task.category + 1 }}_li">
      <span>
        <span class="panel_title">
          {{ task.title }}
        </span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great, I didn't know about $parent at all, thanks! 
Do you know how I could go about making these loop into the same list? Like so: jsfiddle.net/3f2anqva

Answer (score 1):

Each `ng-repeat` creates a child scope with the passed data, and also adds an additional `$index` variable in that scope.

So what you need to do is reach up to the parent scope, and use that `$index`.

HTML :

```
<li ng-repeat="tasks in tasklist.tasks | orderBy:'category' | filter: {category: cat}" class="cat{{ $parent.$index + 1 }}_li">
```